Golang unexpected fault address fatal error: fault - but C code works
i try to call a memory address, which contains in my case a calculator app. With my C code it successfully runs the calculator, but with my Golang code i will get the error "unexpected fault address 0xe852455a4d". As you can see on the screenshot, the memory address exists and it contains the calculator app.
Why does that happens? Is it a Golang bug, or do i something wrong?

C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    // Path to the custom calc.exe file
    const char* filePath = "calc.exe";

    // Read the contents of the custom calc.exe file
    FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(fileSize);
    if (bytes == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    fread(bytes, 1, fileSize, file);
    fclose(file);

    // Allocate memory using VirtualAlloc
    void* memoryPtr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, fileSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (memoryPtr == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        free(bytes);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Address: %x\n", memoryPtr);

    // Copy the contents of custom calc.exe into allocated memory
    memcpy(memoryPtr, bytes, fileSize);
    free(bytes);
    //Sleep(23232323);

    ((void(*)())memoryPtr)();

    return 0;
}


Golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
    "time"
)

const (
    MEM_COMMIT             = 0x1000
    MEM_RESERVE            = 0x2000
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
)

func main() {
    // Path to the custom calc.exe file
    filePath := "calc.exe"

    // Read the contents of the custom calc.exe file
    bytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading file:", err)
        return
    }

    // Allocate memory using VirtualAlloc
    memoryPtr, _, err := syscall.Syscall6(syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32").NewProc("VirtualAlloc").Addr(), 4,
        0, uintptr(len(bytes)), MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 0, 0)
    if memoryPtr == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Error allocating memory:", err)
        return
    }

    copy((*[1 << 30]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(memoryPtr))[:len(bytes)], bytes)

    fmt.Printf("Address: %x\n", memoryPtr);
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    callableFunc := *(*func())(unsafe.Pointer(memoryPtr))
    callableFunc()
}


Error Log
unexpected fault address 0xe852455a4d
fatal error: fault
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xe852455a4d pc=0x1f301f]

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw({0x2109d1?, 0xed87958cd74?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:1077 +0x65 fp=0xc00006de30 sp=0xc00006de00 pc=0x192d65
runtime.sigpanic()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:377 +0xd0 fp=0xc00006de78 sp=0xc00006de30 pc=0x1a5370
main.main()
        C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/stackoverflow2.go:42 +0x21f fp=0xc00006df40 sp=0xc00006de78 pc=0x1f301f
runtime.main()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:267 +0x2b2 fp=0xc00006dfe0 sp=0xc00006df40 pc=0x1955b2
runtime.goexit()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc00006dfe8 sp=0xc00006dfe0 pc=0x1bd6e1

goroutine 2 [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xce fp=0xc000035fa8 sp=0xc000035f88 pc=0x1959ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.forcegchelper()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:322 +0xb8 fp=0xc000035fe0 sp=0xc000035fa8 pc=0x195858
runtime.goexit()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc000035fe8 sp=0xc000035fe0 pc=0x1bd6e1
created by runtime.init.6 in goroutine 1
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:310 +0x1a

goroutine 3 [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xce fp=0xc000037f78 sp=0xc000037f58 pc=0x1959ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.bgsweep(0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:280 +0x94 fp=0xc000037fc8 sp=0xc000037f78 pc=0x180a74
runtime.gcenable.func1()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x25 fp=0xc000037fe0 sp=0xc000037fc8 pc=0x175e05
runtime.goexit()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc000037fe8 sp=0xc000037fe0 pc=0x1bd6e1
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x66

goroutine 4 [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0xc00001a070?, 0x231f88?, 0x1?, 0x0?, 0xc000032b60?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xce fp=0xc000047f70 sp=0xc000047f50 pc=0x1959ce
runtime.goparkunlock(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:404
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x2aeaa0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x49 fp=0xc000047fa0 sp=0xc000047f70 pc=0x17e349
runtime.bgscavenge(0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x3c fp=0xc000047fc8 sp=0xc000047fa0 pc=0x17e8dc
runtime.gcenable.func2()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0x25 fp=0xc000047fe0 sp=0xc000047fc8 pc=0x175da5
runtime.goexit()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc000047fe8 sp=0xc000047fe0 pc=0x1bd6e1
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0xa5

goroutine 5 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x400000?, 0x100039e70?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x301fe0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xce fp=0xc000039e28 sp=0xc000039e08 pc=0x1959ce
runtime.runfinq()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:193 +0x107 fp=0xc000039fe0 sp=0xc000039e28 pc=0x174ec7
runtime.goexit()
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650 +0x1 fp=0xc000039fe8 sp=0xc000039fe0 pc=0x1bd6e1
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/mfinal.go:163 +0x3d
exit status 2


[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0xe852455a4d pc=0x1f301f]. This message tells you that you have tried to access an address that is not in your process address space. You would need to use the debugger to narrow it down to the actual source language statement.

How about adding a code of calc.exe for a Minimal Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
